# clickable div link, but with a list inside (that validates)

Tags: css, validation, html

The goal is a squarish div that is clickable as a link, and which contains a list.

This validates:

```
<div class="game">
    <a href="link.html">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <span class="name">Name</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and with the `<a>` set to `display: block` I get the fully-clickable div effect I want.

But this, for obvious reasons, does not validate (even though browsers all make it work):

```
<div class="game">
    <a href="link.html">
        <span class="name">Name</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 1</li>
            <li>Thing 2</li>
            <li>Thing X</li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div>
```

is there a way to have a list inside my div, have the entire div be one block link, and still validate?

Answer (score 2):

It might not be valid HTML4, but it's definitely valid HTML5 - in HTML5, you're allowed to have `<ul>`s inside `<a>`s.

Comment: As long as your doctype is as follows: <!doctype html> then your all good.

Answer (score 1):

Put an onclick event on your div and do away with the anchor altogether:

```
<div class="game" onclick="location.href='link.html';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span class="name">Name</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Thing 1</li>
        <li>Thing 2</li>
        <li>Thing X</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not very pretty but it should validate.

Edit: Also most browsers are fine with div:hover css so you should still be able to get your anchor style css.